# Lattice with trivial spinor norm

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, lattices

Let $\Lambda$ be a non-degenerate lattice (over $\mathbb{Z}$) with quadratic form $q$. I define the spinor norm $\theta \colon O(\Lambda_\mathbb{R} )\to \lbrace\pm 1\rbrace$ as follows:

For a reflection $s_v \in O(\Lambda_\mathbb{R})$ with respect to a vector $v\in \Lambda_\mathbb{R}$ with $q(v) \neq 0$, let

$\theta (s_v) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{if } q(v) > 0 \\
+1 & \text{if } q(v) < 0.
\end{cases}$

Then $\theta$ extends multiplicatively to a homomorphism $\theta\colon O(\Lambda_\mathbb{R}) \to \lbrace \pm 1 \rbrace$.

Is there a non-degenerate, even, isotropic lattice $\Lambda$ of signature $(2,n)$, $1\leq n \leq 9$, such that $\theta(\varphi_\mathbb{R}) = 1$ for all $\varphi \in O(\Lambda)$? More generally, are there (necessary and sufficient) conditions on $\Lambda$ for the spinor norm to be trivial on $O(\Lambda)$?

Comment: [This book](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~drm/manuscripts/eiqf.pdf) may help.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer to my question does not seem to be in there.

Comment: There's no direct answer, but there are techniques that would let you construct such a lattice or prove that it doesn't exist. Everything seems restatable in terms of the signature/discriminant form.

Comment: The book linked by @AlexDegtyarev, on the Wayback Machine: [Miranda and Morrison - Embeddings of integral quadratic forms](https://web.archive.org/web/20180412212946/http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~drm/manuscripts/eiqf.pdf).